# Evaluating $\frac{2013^3-2\cdot 2013^2\cdot 2014+3\cdot 2013\cdot 2014^2-2014^3+1}{2013\cdot 2014}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What is the value of $$\frac{2013^3-2\cdot 2013^2\cdot 2014+3\cdot 2013\cdot 2014^2-2014^3+1}{2013\cdot 2014}?$$

---

What I have tried:

$$\implies\frac{2013^2(2013-2\cdot2014)+2014^2(3\cdot 2013-2014)+1}{2013\cdot 2014}$$
$$\implies\frac{2013^2(-2015)+2014^2(4025)+1}{2013\cdot 2014}$$

I'm not sure what to do next...

Help is appreciated!

Furthermore, if you are nice, could you also help me on [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3098173/transferring-bases-of-numbers)([Transferring bases of numbers.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3098173/transferring-bases-of-numbers)) too?

Thanks!

Max0815

Comment: Hint:  make $(2013-2014)^3$ a term in the numerator

Comment: Yeah I found out thx though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can complete the cube of the difference.

$$
=\frac{2013^3-3\cdot2013^2\cdot2014+3\cdot2013\cdot2014^2-2014^3+2013^2\cdot2014+1}{2013\cdot2014}
$$
$$
=\frac{(2013-2014)^3+2013^2\cdot2014+1}{2013\cdot2014}=\frac{2013^2\cdot2014}{2013\cdot2014}=2013
$$

Comment: Oh thanks I see!

Answer (score 1):

$$= \frac {(2013-2014)^3+2013^2\cdot 2014+1}{2013\cdot 2014}$$

$$=\frac {-1+2013^2\cdot 2014+1}{2013\cdot 2014}$$

$$=2013$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint

Choose $2013=a$

$$\dfrac{a^3-2a^2(a+1)+3a(a+1)^2-(a+1)^3+1}{a(a+1)}$$

$$=\dfrac{-3a(a+1)+a(a+1)\{3(a+1)-2a\}}{a(a+1)}$$

$$=-3+3+a$$ as $a(a+1)\ne0$

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Let $a=2013$ and $b=2014$. You have:

$$\frac{a^3 - 2a^2b + 3ab^2 - b^3 + 1}{ab}$$

Recall that $(a-b)^3=a^3-3a^2b+3ab^2-b^3$ and use that to simplify.