# What is the greatest possible value of $a + b + c$ for which there are at least two values of $n$ such that $C_n - B_n = A_n^2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

For a positive integer $n$ and nonzero digits $a$, $b$, and $c$, let $A_n$ be the $n$-digit integer each of whose digits is equal to $a$; let $B_n$ be the $n$-digit integer each of whose digits is equal to $b$, and let $C_n$ be the $2n$-digit (not $n$-digit) integer each of whose digits is equal to $c$. What is the greatest possible value of $a + b + c$ for which there are at least two values of $n$ such that $C_n - B_n = A_n^2$?

---

What I have tried:

> I start by trying $n = 1$ and $n = 2$. These give the system of equations $11c - b = a^2$ and $1111c - 11b = (11a)^2$. These imply that $a^2 = 9c$, so the possible $(a, c)$ pairs are $(9, 9)$, $(6, 4)$, and $(3, 1)$. The first puts $b$ out of range but the second makes $b = 8$. We now know the answer is at least $6 + 8 + 4 = 18$.

How should I continue?

Help is appreciated!
Also, if you are nice, can you PLEASE help me on [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3098173/ns-base-5-and-base-6-representations-treated-as-base-10-yield-sum-s-for) question([$N$'s base-5 and base-6 representations, treated as base-10, yield sum $S$. For which $N$ are $S$'s rightmost two digits the same as $2N$'s?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3098173/ns-base-5-and-base-6-representations-treated-as-base-10-yield-sum-s-for))?

Thanks!

Max0815

Comment: How do you get from your first two equations to $a^2=9c?$  You can divide the second by $11$ to get $101c-b=11a^2$

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by your first equation. And how does dividing by 11 help though... :( I'm confused

Comment: You said correctly that for $n=1$ you have $11c-b=a^2$ and for $n=2$ you have $1111c-11b=(11a)^2$.  I don't see how either of those leads to $a^2=9c$.  I divided the $n=2$ equation by $11$ to get my result, which I think is a simpler equation to work with.

Comment: Right... ahh I think I had an algebra error. Let me try again with ur equation...

Comment: @RossMillikan Now subtract $11c - b = a^2$ from $101c - b = 11a^2$. Doesn't it give $90c = 10a^2$?

Comment: No I didn't divide by 11 I multipled the other equation by 11 and subtracted and then divided. Not sure where I messed up... Turns out I didn't, but my process was too complicated...

Comment: How should I continue though?

Comment: I'm thinking that we now only need to know whether $a + b + c = 20$ might work for any larger $n$, but I'm unsure how to check this...

Comment: Yes, I didn't see that.  But that isn't enough.  You need to check that $4444-88=66^2$, which it is.  The other two solutions do not work.

Comment: There are two other solutions?

Comment: You mentioned $(3,1)$ and $(9,9)$.  They solve $a^2=9c$, but that is only necessary, not sufficient.  When you plug into the original equations they fail.

Comment: Ah right... hmm let me trial and error some more...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We note that $A_n = a\cdot\dfrac{10^n - 1}{9}$, $B_n = b\cdot\dfrac{10^n - 1}{9}$, and $C_n = c\cdot\dfrac{10^{2n} - 1}{9}$. Then, we have $c\cdot\dfrac{10^{2n} - 1}{9} - b\cdot\dfrac{10^n - 1}{9} = (a\cdot\dfrac{10^n - 1}{9})^2$, and when we multiply everything out and simplify, we get $$9c\cdot10^n + 9c - 9b = a^2 \cdot 10^n - a^2 \implies (9c-a^2) \cdot 10^n + 9c-9b + a^2 = 0$$
Now, note that since if two distinct values of $n$, say $x$ and $y$ work, then we get the equations$(9c-a^2) \cdot 10^x + 9c-9b + a^2 = 0$ and $(9c-a^2) \cdot 10^y + 9c-9b + a^2 = 0$, and subtracting gets $(9c-a^2) \cdot (10^y - 10^x) = 0$, and since $10^y - 10^x \neq 0$, we must have $9c = a^2$. Therefore, we get three solutions for $(a,c)$, which only $(6,4)$ gives an integer value of $b$, which means the solution $(a,b,c)$ is $(6,8,4) \implies 18$.

You were on the right track for finding $a^2 = 9c$, however, the problem does become easier after converting to $10^n$ instead of dealing with increasingly larger numbers; another way was to prove that $(a,c) = (3,1)$ is too small even if $b = 9$, and that $(a,c) = (9,9)$ has no solutions by noting that $C_n - (A_n)^2 = B_n$ and that $99 - 9^2 = 9(11-9) = 18$, $9999 - (99)^2 = 99(101-99) = 99 \cdot 2$, and that $9_n - (9_n)^2 = 2 \cdot 9_n$. (This can be proved by realizing that $C_n = A_n \cdot (A_n + 2)$.) Since $2 \cdot 9_n$ can never be equal to $B_n$, as $2 \cdot 9_n$ has a units digit of $8$ but it's first digit is $1$, we are done.

Comment: Ah thanks!!! I get it now!!!