# How many distinct values does $f(x)$ assume for $x \ge 0$?

Tags: number-theory

Let $$f(x)=\sum_{k=2}^{10}(\lfloor kx \rfloor -k \lfloor x \rfloor),$$ where $\lfloor r \rfloor$ denotes the greatest integer less than or equal to $r$. How many distinct values does $f(x)$ assume for $x \ge 0$?

---

I first started out this problem with the memory that once a math teacher told me that $x = \lfloor x \rfloor + \{ x \}$ where $\{ x \}$ is the fractional part of $x$. I plug this in and get we have

$$f(x) = \sum_{k=2}^{10} (\lfloor k \lfloor x \rfloor +k \{ x \} \rfloor - k \lfloor x \rfloor)$$

The function can then be simplified into

$$f(x) = \sum_{k=2}^{10} ( k \lfloor x \rfloor + \lfloor k \{ x \} \rfloor - k \lfloor x \rfloor)$$

which becomes

$$f(x) = \sum_{k=2}^{10} \lfloor k \{ x \} \rfloor$$
I don't know how to continue.

Am I on the right track? If so, how should I continue? If not, what path should I take?

Also, if you are nice, could you please also help me on [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3098173/ns-base-5-and-base-6-representations-treated-as-base-10-yield-sum-s-for) problem([$N$'s base-5 and base-6 representations, treated as base-10, yield sum $S$. For which $N$ are $S$'s rightmost two digits the same as $2N$'s?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3098173/ns-base-5-and-base-6-representations-treated-as-base-10-yield-sum-s-for))?

Thanks!

Max0815

Comment: What happens when $\frac1k\le\{x\}\leq\frac1{k-1}$?

Comment: @Jens Schwaiger I'm not sure, am I supposed to plug that into the function?

Comment: You should best different C.

Comment: You should best different cases. If for instance $\{x\}<\frac1{10}$ the sum is 0. For $\frac1{10}\leq\{x\}<\frac19$ you should get 1. And so on.

Comment: A comment by [ETS1331](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/418667/ets1331) to my now deleted answer from yesterday points out I was wrong, and also linked to [2016 AMC 10B Problems/Problem 25](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/2016_AMC_10B_Problems/Problem_25) which, as the page title shows, gives where the problem comes from, the entire text of it and what seems to be a correct solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.
Yay thanks Jens S. for helping me!