# Given a strip of 7 small triangles each with an area of 1, what is the area of the created trapezoid below the strip?

Tags: geometry, triangles

All of the triangles in the diagram below are similar to isosceles triangle $ABC$, in which $AB=AC$. Each of the 7 smallest triangles has area 1, and $\triangle ABC$ has area 40. What is the area of trapezoid $DBCE$?

[image]

---

Well I approached this problem by trying to find similar triangle ratios.
Let the small triangle base be $x$. Then $DE=4x$. That's all I got lol. I couldn't find any other ratios or side lengths. Then, I manually drew triangles composing $\triangle ADE$. This gave me 16 triangles that make up $\triangle ADE$. So thus, $\triangle ADE$ has an area of 16, and trapezoid $BDEC$ has an area of $40-16=\boxed{24}$. Although this is correct, my method of solving comes at a great risk. Is there any better method of solving this question?

Also, if you are nice, could you please also help me on [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3098173/ns-base-5-and-base-6-representations-treated-as-base-10-yield-sum-s-for)([$N$'s base-5 and base-6 representations, treated as base-10, yield sum $S$. For which $N$ are $S$'s rightmost two digits the same as $2N$'s?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3098173/ns-base-5-and-base-6-representations-treated-as-base-10-yield-sum-s-for)) question?

Thanks!

Max0815

Comment: ADE is similar to each of the small triangles.  The base is 4 times the size.

The area is $4^2$ times as large.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The uppermost triangle has base three times larger than one of the smallest triangles, so its area is nine times larger. That means the area you're looking for is $40-9\times1-7\times1=24$.

Comment: How do you know that it is?

Comment: Is there some side length ratio to prove this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. This is a question about similar triangles and scale factors. Since the length scale factor is $3$, the area scale factor is $9$.

Comment: How do you know that the side length has a scale factor of 3?

Comment: Ah me being dumb I see!