# Three numbers a, b, c, over 1 have a sum of $\frac{6}{7}$. What is a+b+c?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given that there are three integers $a, b,$ and $c$ such that $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}=\frac{6}{7}$, what is the value of a+b+c?

---

Immediately, I see that I should combine the left hand side. Doing such results in the equation $$\frac{ab+ac+bc}{abc}=\frac{6x}{7x}.$$ This branches into two equation $$ab+ac+bc=6x$$$$abc=7x.$$ From this, I can tell that one of a, b, or c must be a multiple of 7, and the other two are a factor of $x$. Now, I do trial and error, but I find this very tiring and time consuming. Is there a better method?

Also, if you are nice, could you also help me on [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3098173/ns-base-5-and-base-6-representations-treated-as-base-10-yield-sum-s-for)([$N$'s base-5 and base-6 representations, treated as base-10, yield sum $S$. For which $N$ are $S$'s rightmost two digits the same as $2N$'s?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3098173/ns-base-5-and-base-6-representations-treated-as-base-10-yield-sum-s-for)) question?

Thanks!

Max0815

Comment: You don't actually know that one of them must be 7.  You know that one of them must be divisible by 7.

Comment: good point.....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your argument isn't correct as stated due to the issue pointed out by Dan Uznanski in the comments. But following your idea of combining things, we have

$$6abc = 7(ab + ac + bc)$$

so that $7 | abc$ and $6 | (ab + ac + bc)$. Let's assume that $a$ is divisible by $7$, so clearly $a \ge 7$ (assuming that all the numbers are positive). It then follows that

$$\frac 1 b + \frac 1 c = \frac 6 7 - \frac 1 a \ge \frac 5 7 > \frac 2 3$$

Now if $b$ and $c$ were both strictly greater than $2$, we would have a contradiction (why?). We can therefore assume $c = 2$ and reduce to

$$\frac 1 a + \frac 1 b = \frac 5 {14}.$$
Now repeat the ideas: We have

$$\frac 1 b = \frac 5 {14} - \frac 1 a \ge \frac 5 {14} - \frac 1 7 = \frac{3}{14} \implies b \le \frac{14}{3} \implies b \le 4.$$

This is now a very finite set to check.

Comment: Was writing this up, but you beat me. Nice solution!

Comment: Ok, I got it! Thanks!

Comment: Wait a sec I don't get why would we have contradiction if both b and c < 2?

Comment: @Max0815:  It was a contradiction if $b$ and $c$ were both $gt 2$.  The largest $\frac 1b+\frac1c$ could be would be $\frac 23$.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the greedy algorithm wins here, and quite quickly.

Let's assume wlog that $a\le b\le c$.

If $a=1$, then we're already higher than $6/7$, so let's try $a=2$.  Now we have $\frac{1}{b} + \frac{1}{c} = \frac{6}{7} - \frac{1}{2} = \frac{5}{14}$.  Now, $b$ has to be at least $3$; let's try it, we get ... $\frac{1}{c} = \frac{5}{14} - \frac{1}{3} = \frac{1}{42}$.

Oh.

$$\frac{6}{7} = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{42}$$