# For distinct positive reals $A$ and $B$, neither equal to $1$, such that $\log_A B = \log_B A$, find $AB$.

Tags: logarithms

> Suppose $A$ and $B$ are positive real numbers for which $\log_AB=\log_BA$. If neither $A$ nor $B$ is $1$, and if $A\neq B$, find the value of $AB$.

So I use the change of base theorem getting 
$$\frac{\log B}{\log A}=\frac{\log A}{\log B}$$ 
I then cross multiply getting 
$$\left(\log A\right)^2=\left(\log B\right)^2$$ 
which simplifies to 
$$\log A=\log B$$ 
It seems that this is a dead end, as I see no other solution other than $A=B$.

I could also go on to have 
$$\frac{\log A}{\log 5+\log2}=\frac{\log B}{\log 5+\log2}$$ 
which would give me 
$$\log A(\log 5+\log2)=\log B(\log 5+\log2)$$ 
but sadly, I don't know how to multiply logs so I'm stuck this way.

Going literally by the log definition gives me 
$$B=A^{\log_BA}$$ 
and doesn't get anywhere. Help would be appreciated!

Also, if you are nice, could you also help me on [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3098173/ns-base-5-and-base-6-representations-treated-as-base-10-yield-sum-s-for)([$N$'s base-5 and base-6 representations, treated as base-10, yield sum $S$. For which $N$ are $S$'s rightmost two digits the same as $2N$'s?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3098173/ns-base-5-and-base-6-representations-treated-as-base-10-yield-sum-s-for)) problem?

Thanks!

Max0815

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can avoid going to a third base. Just use that
$$
\log_BA=\frac{1}{\log_AB}
$$
(which is legal because $B\ne1$) so your equation yields $(\log_AB)^2=1$, hence
$$
\log_AB=1 \qquad\text{or}\qquad \log_AB=-1
$$
The former implies $A=B$, so it has to be discarded. Hence $B=A^{-1}$.

Comment: Oh, a generalization of it, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

$x^{2}=y^{2}$ does  not imply $x=y$. It implies $x=y$ or $x =-y$. Hence $\log\, A =\pm \log\, B$. Since $A \neq B$ we get $\log\, A =-\log\, B$ which can be written as $\log\, A+\log\, B=0$ or $\log\, AB=0$. This means $AB=1$.

Answer (score 1):

> It seems that this is a dead end, as I see no other solution other than A=B.

Except, as you now realize, the one and only other option is to  have $\log A = - \log B$ (which is possible if $A < 1 < B$ or $B < 1 < A$).

From which it follows $A = e^{\log A} = e^{-\log B} = \frac 1B$ and ... you are back on the right track and you reach a "live" end:

$AB = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

I found a really simple solution using only the definition of log and basic exponential rules.

Let $\log_{A}B = x = \log_{B}A$.
Using the definition of log,
$$
B^x = A\,\,\text{and}\,\,A^x = B.\tag{1}
$$
$$
A^x = B \implies (A^x)^x = B^x
\implies A^{x^2} = B^x. \tag{2} 
$$
Using equations $(1)$ and $(2)$,
$$
A^{x^2} = A
$$
Since $A$ is not equal to $1$, and the bases are identical, we can equate
the powers:
$$
x^2 = 1 \implies x =\pm 1.
$$

Case 1: $x = 1$

By equation $(1)$, $A = B$, which is not allowed by the question.

Case 2: $x = -1$

$A$ and $B$ become reciprocals of each other, and $\boxed{AB = 1}$.

Comment: This is the same answer as others above.

Comment: I mean this is basically the accepted answer except you've added an obfuscation layer with the $x$ substitution. Regardless, thanks for your answer :) appreciate it

Comment: That occurred to me but I saw that most of these answers included a step that doesn't seem right to someone just learning the logarithmic rules, such as me.
I included this answer for that audience.